# Shopify Google forms / calendar booking

Tags: shopify, google-calendar-api, google-forms

This may be a bit vague but.
Is it possible to create an events booking system using Google calendar and maybe Google forms and then pay for that booking with Shopify checkout?

Can someone point me in the right direction of what components / libraries or APIs I need to use please.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to through Shopify Storefront API. However, I think Shopify checkout needs a variant id to work which means the product (or in your case booking) needs to be in your Shopify account. But it should be easy to use Shopify Admin API to create the product in your shopify account and retrieve back the variant id so you can proceed with the checkout process.